# Database changes on AWS real time sync to GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform

We have Postgresql on AWS. All realtime changes from Portal UI are captured on this database. However there is a request to move these changes in realtime or near realtime to GCP.

Purpose: We want various consumers to ingest data from GCP, instead of master data source in PostgresAWS.

When a customer table (in AWS Postgres) is being inserted with a new customer record, then I want to immediately populate that record in JSON format in GCP pub sub topic.

Please let me know any reference to move a database table specific data across cloud as and when any DML event occurs?

Please note that am new to GCP and learning and exploring :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases use log shipping to update slaves/replicas. In your case, you want to update two targets (database, Cloud Pub/Sub) by having the database do the Pub/Sub update. That might be possible but will require development work.

PostgreSQL does not have a native ability to update Pub/Sub. Instead, change your requirements so that the application/service that is updating the database then updates Pub/Sub.

If you really want PostgreSQL to do this task, you will need to use PostgreSQL triggers and write a trigger function in C with the Google Cloud Pub/Sub REST API.

[PostgreSQL Trigger Example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/trigger-example.html)

[PostgreSQL Event Trigger Example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/event-trigger-example.html)

[Event triggers for PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.EventTriggers)

[Cloud Pub/Sub API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest)